# Верстка меню

Tags: html, javascript, css

хочу сделать чтоб в меню горизонтальном была нажатой (активной) та кнопка меню страница страница которой открыта, но не получается, помогите кто чем может, спасибо

Comment: Вы не используете никаких серверных языков, типа: PHP, ASP.NET, Ruby или тому подобные? Только HTML и JS?

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос составлен корректно, и задачу действительно нужно решить исключительно на клиенте, то можно сделать например так: http://jsfiddle.net/b8bqz/

```js
var loc = window.location.href.split('?')[0]
$('.nav a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf(loc) == 0) $(this).parent().addClass('active')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://jsfiddle.net/">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Но вообще-то лучше на сервере определять, какой пункт меню активен.

Comment: Елена, а откуда тут бутстрап ?

Comment: подключен из cdn. Для сути задачи не имеет значения, но с ним проще сделать вид, что это меню.

Comment: мне кажется лучше prop использовать http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/b8bqz/2/

Comment: вообще да, prop лучше. Но сравнивать не целиком строку на точное соответствие, а чтобы адрес текущей страницы начинался с адреса, указанного в пункте меню. Менюшки бывают и многоуровневыми.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**:

```
.active{ background: red!important;}
```

**HTML**: (Немного до-изменил Ваш: добавил ссылки и выправил ошибки)

```
<div class="menu"> 
        <ul> 
            <li><a href='?page=main'>One</a></li> 
            <li><a href='?page=product'>Two</a></li> 
            <li><a href='?page=three'>Three</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="submenu"> 
            <li><a href="?page=four">Four</a></li> 
            <li><a href="?page=five">Five</a></li> 
            <li><a href="?page=six">Six</a></li> 
        </ul> 
        <ul> 
            <li><a href='?page=contacts'>Seven</a></li> 
            <li><a href='?page=order_page'>Eight</a></li> 
        </ul> 
    </div>
```

**JS**: (С помощью ***jQuery***, все это дело организовать намного проще. Советую поинтересоваться)

```
var mainMenu = document.getElementsByTagName("div"); //ищем теги div

for(var i=0;i<mainMenu.length;i++){
    if(mainMenu[i].getAttribute("class")=="menu"){
        mainMenu = mainMenu[i]; //ищем и запаковываем div с классом menu
        break;
    }
}

var aTag = mainMenu.getElementsByTagName("a"); //ищем все теги А

var thisPage;

for(var i=0;i<aTag.length;i++){

    thisPage = aTag[i].href.split("?"); //делим путь по разделителю "?"

    if(RegExp("^http:\/\/.*\?"+thisPage[1]+'.*').test(window.location.href)){
        aTag = aTag[i]; //сохраняем наш тег
        break;
    }
}

var liTag = aTag.parentNode; //выбираем наш родительский тег (li)
liTag.setAttribute("class","active"); //добавляем класс
```

Вот Вам готовый, рабочий ***html***: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jqdv3r5fllw1orz/testmenu.html - анализируйте)

Comment: меню бывают вложенными :)

Comment: та они всякие бывают, нету примера от человека )

Comment: это-то да, пример бы был значительной помощью.

А вот ещё я смотрю на ваш пример и никак не пойму: а откуда id берётся?

Comment: ссылка 
/?page=main
и меню
<div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href='?page=main'></a></li>
                <li><a href='?page=product'></a></li>
                <li><a href='#'></a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href=""></a></li>
                        <li><a href=""></a></li>
                        <li><a href=""></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='?page=contacts'></a></li>
                <li><a href='?page=order_page'></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div

Comment: Пробуйте, теперь должно сработать. По крайней мере у меня всё работает. Учтите! Ссылки с пустым местом или решёткой - не изменяют своей локации, так что и меню не переключит.

Comment: спасибо огромное за помощь, но не работает к сожалению ((

Comment: У меня 2ва предположения:

- Вы задаете свой скрипт над страницей. Соответственно, ваш скрипт ищет меню, которого на тот момент еще не существует. Так как страница с меню загружается после скрипта. 
Для решения этой проблемы есть 2ва варианта:
 
1вый - если меню сверху, то взять всё это дело в window.onload = function(){ //Ваш код }
2рой - расположить свой JS в низу тега BODY


- Или Вы не исправили те ошибки в HTML, которые у вас были, соответственно структура кода нарушена из этого и ошибки.

Вот Вам готовый, рабочий html:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jqdv3r5fllw1orz/testmenu.html
Анализируйте

Comment: спасибо большое за внимание, действительно нужно было расположить внизу страницы, т.е. перед закрывающим боди, спасибо